# Проблема с расширением экрана

Tags: unity3d

Вопрос касается UI-элементов, да и вообще объектов.

Вообщем, когда я добавляю различные изображения, тексты и т. д в Editor, все смотрится нормально. Но когда запускаю скомпилированный проект, то в нем все становится верх дном. Текст не там, где должен быть, и остальные объекты не на своем месте. Говорят, что то связано с соотношением сторон, кто знает пожалуйста поподробнее.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле в 2ч словах сложно описать,но если попытаться, то ui объекты должны быть прикреплены к панелям и их отображение(не обязательно) может редактироваться скриптами.Все есть в официальной документации.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html